# local variable in the select and groupby inside a cursor

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am relatively new to db and Sqlserver and am having some problems. So, I have a procedure in which i am using a cursor and each time a cursor fetches next i am providing many local variables to be used in the cursor.

```
DECLARE @tempTotalValue TABLE (Id int, IT float, Total float,  PlannedDate smalldatetime, PeriodStart smalldatetime)

DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR 

SELECT 
 ...,
 ...,  
 ...,
 ...,
 ...

FROM 
Order
```

Now, inside the cursor i am executing another procedure (the design of this procedure is fixed and cannot be changed). That procedure returns some value which i am insert into some table variable which i am using it further in my procedure to calculate some values and return it.

```
OPEN curs

FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @Id, @IP ,@FromDate, @ToDate, @Length, @Amount 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    BEGIN 

        DECLARE @tempIT TABLE(TI nvarchar(20), PlannedDate smalldatetime, PeriodStart smalldatetime, PeriodLength smallint, PeriodAmount float)

        INSERT INTO @tempIT EXEC IPDates @IP, @FromDate, @ToDate, @Length, @Amount //cannot change this procedure

        DELETE FROM @tempIT WHERE (YEAR(PlannedDate) < YEAR(DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0))) OR YEAR(PlannedDate) > YEAR(DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 1));

        INSERT INTO @tempTotalValue 

        SELECT   
            @Id, // *this is the problem*
            0,
            PeriodAmount, 
            PlannedDate,
            PeriodStart
        FROM 
            @tempIT
        GROUP BY 
            --@Id // Not possible but i want to do it 

    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @Id, @IP, @FromDate, @ToDate, @Length, @Amount

    DELETE FROM @tempIT

END 
CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs

Select * from @tempTotalValue
END
```

The problem i am facing is that that the one of the local variable named 'Id' is in my cursor and i am directly using that variable in the table which i am returning for my procedure. Now, i want to group by my result according to this Id. But thats not possible. For example in the picture below i want to group by the 4th and 5th row as they are of the same id and in the future when i have some values in the second (IT) column. I want to display just one idinstead of same ids multiple time and in the IT column want to show the addition of all the same id's.

[image: Table]

Comment: So which PlannedDate and PeriodStart do you want to show when you combine rows 4 and 5? What do you want to do when PeriodAmount/Total is a different value on the two rows? When you collapse rows by grouping on one column, any other columns where the values are different have to be either aggregated or not included.

Answer (score 0):

If you frame a dynamic sql, you will be able to "Execute" it after. By then, you would have your Id value set in the GROUP BY clause and sql executes like any normal sql insert.